# Extending YOLOv5 pretrained dataset to contain custom license plates

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

In python I have a pytorch model for object detecting using YOLO that I load like this:

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5l', pretrained=True)
```

It works fine for detecting cars and other vehicles, but I also need it to be able to detect (not recognize) license plates so that I can blur them. Is it possible to extend the dataset for pre-training with more training images containing license plates so that it can also detect license plates? It would be fine if I had to retrain the model, but being able to extend the dataset it was already trained on would be nice, since I do not have the resources to collect that much training data. It would be nice to know if this is feasible or not, or if there is a simpler alternative for blurring license plates.

Comment: that's called "transfer learning" or fine tuning or adaptation.